# How do i change this from 12-hours clock to 24-hours clock?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to display opening hours on a website and I'm having trouble converting this to a 24-hours clock system - What do i change to make it happend?

```
Cut off code ^

var checkTime = function() {
  var today = weekday[now.getDay()];
  var timeDiv = document.getElementById('timeDiv');
  var dayOfWeek = now.getDay();
  var hour = now.getHours();
  var minutes = now.getMinutes();

  //add AM or PM
  var suffix = hour >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";

  // add 0 to one digit minutes
  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes
  };

  if ((dayOfWeek == 0 || dayOfWeek == 6) && hour >= 13 && hour <= 23) {
    hour = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1); //i.e. show 1:15 instead of 13:15
    timeDiv.innerHTML = 'it\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + ' - we\'re open!';
    timeDiv.className = 'open';
  } else if ((dayOfWeek == 3 || dayOfWeek == 4 || dayOfWeek == 5) && hour >= 16 && hour <= 23) {
    hour = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1);
    timeDiv.innerHTML = 'it\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + ' - we\'re open!';
    timeDiv.className = 'open';
  } else {
    if (hour == 0 || hour > 12) {
      hour = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1); //i.e. show 1:15 instead of 13:15
    }
    timeDiv.innerHTML = 'It\'s ' + today + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + suffix + ' - we\'re closed!';
    timeDiv.className = 'closed';
  }
};

var currentDay = weekday[now.getDay()];
var currentDayID = "#" + currentDay; //gets todays weekday and turns it into id
$(currentDayID).toggleClass("today"); //hightlights today in the view hours modal popup

setInterval(checkTime, 1000);
checkTime();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Working with Date object is really hard. I prefer to use http://momentjs.com/

Comment: This is one of my first times using javascript so i don't know anything about it.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the lines with `//i.e. show 1:15 instead of 13:15` on them?

Comment: @Quantumplate yeah i did, didn't help.

Comment: Try the docs(http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)?

It states                            

H, HH       24 hour time
h, or hh    12 hour time (use in conjunction with a or A)

Thus, stating your time as HH will give you 24h format, and hh will give 12h format.

Comment: @Noor - There are no docs, found this on jsfiddle.

Comment: can u send the the jsFiddle link plz

Comment: http://codepen.io/zeinab92/pen/xwWGWM/ - Sorry it was codepen, not jsfiddle.

Comment: Sorry not all lines have that comment on them.  Comment out the 3 occurances of this... `hour = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1);`

Comment: @Quantumplate - Just did and nothing changes :/

Comment: Your question should include what you expect the output to be and what you actually get. Saying "it doesn't work" doesn't help. "*What do i change to make it happend?*". What is "it"?

Comment: The Output is still the same. It still displays 1:38 AM instead of 01:38

Comment: If you don't want to see the am/pm designator, then remove `+ suffix`.

Comment: I think What RobG is asking is what trigger the change. Any button to press to change the time in 24 hour format? anyway, check this code out, it gives u a 24hr format (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_datetime)

Comment: thanks, but how do i make 1:44 to 01:44 ? now it just says 1:44.

Comment: the "addZero" function from the link in my previous comment does it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
// Pad leading zero if number is < 10
function padZero(i){
  return i < 10 
    ? "0" + i 
    : i;
}

// Construct time string
function formatTime(day, hours, minutes, suffix, state){
  return "It's " + today + " " + padZero(hours) + ":" + padZero(minutes) + suffix + " - we're " + state + "!";
}

// Output time to screen
function checkTime() {
  var today = weekday[now.getDay()];
  var timeDiv = document.getElementById('timeDiv');
  var dayOfWeek = now.getDay();
  var hour = now.getHours();
  var minutes = now.getMinutes();

  //add AM or PM
  //var suffix = hour >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";
  var suffix = "";

  if ((dayOfWeek == 0 || dayOfWeek == 6) && hour >= 13 && hour <= 23) {
    //hour = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1); //i.e. show 1:15 instead of 13:15
    timeDiv.innerHTML = formatTime(today, hour, minutes, suffix, "open");
    timeDiv.className = 'open';
  } else if ((dayOfWeek == 3 || dayOfWeek == 4 || dayOfWeek == 5) && hour >= 16 && hour <= 23) {
    //hour = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1);
    timeDiv.innerHTML = formatTime(today, hour, minutes, suffix, "open");
    timeDiv.className = 'open';
  } else {
    /*if (hour == 0 || hour > 12) {
      hour = ((hour + 11) % 12 + 1); //i.e. show 1:15 instead of 13:15
    }*/
    timeDiv.innerHTML = formatTime(today, hour, minutes, suffix, "closed");
    timeDiv.className = 'closed';
  }
};
```

Changes:

- commented out the 3 lines that convert 24h to 12h
- set `suffix` to "" (you could remove it altogether if you want)
- moved repeated building of time string to it's own function `formatTime()`
- created `padZero()` function to make sure hours and minutes under 10 are padded with a leading '0'.